# Choosing the appropriate wrapper sizes in responsive design

Tags: iphone, css, responsive-design, screen-resolution

With all types of screen resolutions and devices - desktop or mobile, it's kind of hard to pick the right widths for your website. In my case, the website is to present a photographer's work so I've opted for these widths:

- 1340px
- 1180px
- 1000px
- 480px

But say an iphone 4S (native res is 960 x 640) is positioned vertically, what wrapper would the device display? Would it resize the 1000px wrapper into 640px or would it pick the 480px?

Comment: Don't pick wrapper sizes based on devices. Based your breakpoints on when the actual design breaks as you narrow the screen.

Comment: Do you know some about media queries?

Comment: @Danko: No, what do you mean?

Comment: With media queries you can work with the width of the device. And make min and max conditions for each size.Example: The 960 width can work with conditionals between 1000px and 800px.

Comment: You just need to know the width of the biggest screen you want to work for. From that point, as Danko said, you can use media queries to adapt the HTML to the screen needs. For example, iPhone 4-5 in portrait, has 320px width, so you can say **@media ( max-width: 320 ) { <css_styles_for_iphone_portrait> }**. The css styles defined inside this if, only will apply when the screen is an iPhone (or like an iPhone, I suppose other mobiles has more or less the same width).

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to start by learning the basics of Responsive design. Check out : http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

Due to the ever changing nature of device sizes, you may want to avoid trying to target specific devices/resolutions. Start with a narrow screen and expand your window until the layout breaks. Add a breakpoint there. Continue expanding and adding breakpoints as your content dictates.